# Django apps urls.py access

Tags: django

I have one questions I have start project Sth. in sth project I have created app called misc. In view file in misc I have function index. When i try do render it i got NameError misc not found. Here is my urls.py

```
(r'^$'),misc.index,
```

and here is how I add line for installed apps.

```
'Sth.misc',
```

I know that this is easy to do but I'm just beginning and can't handle it. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should either import the `misc` module, or pass the function name as a string to `patterns`:

```
((r'^$'), 'misc.index'),
```